# Tag the 6 first wording days of the month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to find a way to tag the 6 first wording days (Monday to Friday) of the month.

For example, for November I want:

| Date | FlagDate |
| --- | --- |
| 11/01/2021 | True |
| 11/02/2021 | True |
| 11/03/2021 | True |
| 11/04/2021 | True |
| 11/05/2021 | True |
| 11/06/2021 | False |
| 11/07/2021 | False |
| 11/08/2021 | True |
| 11/09/2021 | False |
| 11/10/2021 | False |
| 11/11/2021 | False |
| 11/12/2021 | False |
| 11/13/2021 | False |
| 11/14/2021 | False |
| 11/15/2021 | False |
| 11/16/2021 | False |
| 11/17/2021 | False |
| 11/18/2021 | False |
| 11/19/2021 | False |
| 11/20/2021 | False |
| 11/21/2021 | False |

and so on.

Comment: Do you want this in DAX or M?  And do you want to exclude holidays also?

Comment: Both are fine with me, if possible to exclude french bank holiday ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is M code that adds a column to your existing table.

It assumes that the column Name in your table is `Date`
It also assumes you have a **List** of the relevant holiday dates spanning at least the relevant time frame.  *I obtained the list from `https://publicholidays.fr` and buffered it to keep it from continuously downloading*

See the comments in the M-Code to understand the algorithm

- Note that there is no requirement that the Date column encompasses a full month.  But if it starts on, for example, the 15th, there will be nothing in that month marked TRUE since the first6 are not there.

***Assumption: Date column spans less than 1 year***
*If that is not the case, will need a different algorithm to create the `first6` list.*

**M Code**

```
//Before adding the "Flag" column enter this code to create a buffered list of working days in the months in the Date column
    workingDays = 
        let 
    
    //generate list of all dates from beginning of first month to the last date listed
        dts = List.Transform(
                {Number.From(Date.StartOfMonth(#"Previous Step"[Date]{0}))..
                 Number.From(List.Max(#"Previous Step"[Date]))},each Date.From(_)),

    //Using List.Generate, create a list of working days from the preceding list
    //working days will be days that are Monday-Friday and NOT found in the list of Holiday dates
        wdys = List.Generate(
            ()=>[wd=if Date.DayOfWeek(dts{0})>= Day.Monday 
                        and Date.DayOfWeek(dts{0})<=Day.Friday 
                        and not List.Contains(#"FR Holidays",dts{0}) then dts{0} else null,
                        idx = 0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(dts),
            each [wd=if Date.DayOfWeek(dts{[idx]+1})>= Day.Monday 
                        and Date.DayOfWeek(dts{[idx]+1})<=Day.Friday 
                        and not List.Contains(#"FR Holidays",dts{[idx]+1}) then dts{[idx]+1} else null,
                        idx = [idx]+1],
            each [wd]),

    //clean the wdys List by removing the Nulls
        cleanList = List.RemoveNulls(wdys),

    //create a list of the Months within the workday list
        monthsInList= List.Distinct(List.Transform(cleanList, each Date.Month(_))),

    //Use List.Accumulate to create lists of the first 6 working days in each month
        first6 = List.Accumulate(monthsInList,{}, 
            (state, current)=> state & 
                List.FirstN(List.Select(cleanList,each Date.Month(_)=current),6))
        in List.Buffer(first6),

//Now add a column and set the flag if a Date in the date column is found in the first6 list
    flagged = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step","FlagDate", each List.Contains(workingDays,[Date]), type logical)
in
    flagged
```

[image]

***filtered to show only dates marked `True`***

[image]

***M Code Edited to handle spans of more than one year***
*Change `MonthsInList` to include the year, and also Test for that in the `List.Accumulate` step*

```
//Before adding the "Flag" column enter this code to create a buffered list of working days in the months in the Date column
    workingDays = 
        let 
    
    //generate list of all dates from beginning of first month to the last date listed
        dts = List.Transform(
                {Number.From(Date.StartOfMonth(#"Previous Step"[Date]{0}))..
                 Number.From(List.Max(#"Previous Step"[Date]))},each Date.From(_)),

    //Using List.Generate, create a list of working days from the preceding list
    //working days will be days that are Monday-Friday and NOT found in the list of Holiday dates
        wdys = List.Generate(
            ()=>[wd=if Date.DayOfWeek(dts{0})>= Day.Monday 
                        and Date.DayOfWeek(dts{0})<=Day.Friday 
                        and not List.Contains(#"FR Holidays",dts{0}) then dts{0} else null,
                        idx = 0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(dts),
            each [wd=if Date.DayOfWeek(dts{[idx]+1})>= Day.Monday 
                        and Date.DayOfWeek(dts{[idx]+1})<=Day.Friday 
                        and not List.Contains(#"FR Holidays",dts{[idx]+1}) then dts{[idx]+1} else null,
                        idx = [idx]+1],
            each [wd]),

    //clean the wdys List by removing the Nulls
        cleanList = List.RemoveNulls(wdys),

    //create a list of the Months within the workday list
        monthsInList= List.Distinct(List.Transform(cleanList, each Date.ToText(_,"yyyy-MM"))),

    //Use List.Accumulate to create lists of the first 6 working days in each month
        first6 = List.Accumulate(monthsInList,{}, 
            (state, current)=> state & 
                List.FirstN(List.Select(cleanList,each Date.ToText(_,"yyyy-MM")=current),6))
        in List.Buffer(first6),

//Now add a column and set the flag if a Date in the date column is found in the first6 list
    flagged = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step","FlagDate", each List.Contains(workingDays,[Date]), type logical)
in
    flagged
```

Comment: Hello, amazing job, but Date column spans more than 1 year

Comment: @Kair0  Minor change in the algorithm to handle that.  See Edit

Comment: i'm trying your solution, what is the exact process to make it work ? first creating a date table with a column date then create a blanck query for the buffered list then add the flag column ?

Comment: @Kair0 Briefly: `1:` Create a **List** of the relevant holidays in a separate query which you named **FR Holidays** . `2:` Create your **Date** table with the single column. `3:` Paste the M-Code into your query after the last relevant step (perhaps a `#"Changed Type"`? `4:` Change the name in the code from `#"Previous Step"` to whatever the actual name is.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom column with DAX with the following formula

```
= CONTAINS(TOPN(6,FILTER('Table',WEEKDAY('Table'[Date],2)<6)),'Table'[Date],'Table'[Date])
```

You can update `TopN(6` to accordingly update the number of first working days

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Hello, not working, i only want working days

Comment: Add a filter to it for saturdays and sundays?

Comment: I updated the formula. It should work now

Comment: not sure what you mean by buffered list. But if you already have a date table called "Table" with a column named "Date", then you can simply use the above formula directly to create a new DAX column.

Comment: change the table name (`Table`) and Column name(`Date`) respectively in the formula